# SQL statement to return the Min and Max amount of stock per article for a given Month

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, max, min

I have a table from which I am trying to return the quantity per day that the article was in the system.

Example is in table `Bestand` the are multiple palletes of a different articles that each have a Booking In and Out date; I am try to find out the Min and Max amount of stock that was in the system per article and month.

My thinking is that if I can return the stock quantity for each day and then read out the Min and Max values.

The Timespan would be set at the time of running the SQL and the articles would be fixed.

To find out the quantity for each day I have used the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.artbez1 AS Artikelbezeichnung, 
    b.artikelnr AS Artikelnummer,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TO_DATE('2019-11-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN b.neu_datum AND b.aender_datum THEN 1 * b.menge_ist ELSE 0 END) AS "01 Nov 2019"
FROM
    artikel a, bestand b
WHERE 
    b.artikelnr IN ('273632002', .... (huge long list of numbers) ....)
    AND b.artikelnr = a.artikelnr
GROUP BY 
    a.artbez1, b.artikelnr;
```

This returns for example:

| ARTIKELBEZEICHNUNG | ARTIKELNUMMER | 01 Nov 2019 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SC-4400.CW | 220450002 | 39 |
| S-320.FK120 | 220502004 | 0 |
| H-595.FK120 | 220800004 | 35 |
| AC-548.FK209 | 220948032 | 0 |
| AS-6800.CW | 221355002 | 20 |

I would like return this for each day of the Month and then from that return the Min and Max Value for each Article

I have the following SQL to return the days of a given Month and was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how they could be combined  (If at all possible):

```
SELECT to_date('01.11.2019','dd.mm.yyyy')+LEVEL-1
FROM dual 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(to_date('01.11.2019','dd.mm.yyyy')),'DD')
```

| DATES |
| --- |
| 2019-11-01 00:00:00 |
| 2019-11-02 00:00:00 |
| 2019-11-03 00:00:00 |
| 2019-11-04 00:00:00 |
| 2019-11-05 00:00:00 |
| 2019-11-06 00:00:00 |
| 2019-11-07 00:00:00 |

The result i am try to get would be something like:

| ARTIKELBEZEICHNUNG | ARTIKELNUMMER | Nov 19 Min | Nov 19 Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SC-4400.CW | 220450002 | 5 | 39 |
| S-320.FK120 | 220502004 | 0 | 15 |
| H-595.FK120 | 220800004 | 2 | 35 |
| AC-548.FK209 | 220948032 | 0 | 0 |
| AS-6800.CW | 221355002 | 10 | 20 |

Is this at all possible in SQL?

Thanks for taking the time to read my post.

JeRi

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: And also: **bad habits to kick**: [using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a partitioned outer join:

```sql
WITH calendar ( day ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2019-11-01'
  FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT day + INTERVAL '1' DAY
  FROM   calendar
  WHERE  day < LAST_DAY( DATE '2019-11-01' )
),
daily_totals ( artbez1, Artikelnr, Day, total_menge_ist ) AS (
  SELECT MAX( ab.artbez1 ), 
         ab.artikelnr,
         c.day,
         COALESCE( SUM( ab.menge_ist ), 0 )
  FROM   calendar c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         ( SELECT a.artikelnr,
                  a.artbez1,
                  b.neu_datum,
                  b.aender_datum,
                  b.menge_ist
           FROM   artikel a
                  LEFT JOIN bestand b
                  ON ( a.artikelnr = b.artikelnr )
           -- WHERE  b.artikelnr IN ('273632002', .... (huge long list of numbers) ....)
         ) ab
         PARTITION BY ( ab.artikelnr, ab.artbez1 )
         ON ( c.day BETWEEN ab.neu_datum AND ab.aender_datum )
  GROUP BY ab.artikelnr, c.day
)
SELECT MAX( artbez1 ) AS Artikelbezeichnung,
       artikelnr AS Artikelnummer,
       TRUNC( day, 'MM' ) AS month,
       MIN( total_menge_ist ) AS min_total_menge_ist,
       MAX( total_menge_ist ) AS max_total_menge_ist
FROM   daily_totals
GROUP BY artikelnr, TRUNC( day, 'MM' );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE artikel ( artikelnr, artbez1 ) AS
SELECT 220450002, 'SC-4400.CW'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 220502004, 'S-320.FK120'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 220800004, 'H-595.FK120'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 220948032, 'AC-548.FK209' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 221355002, 'AS-6800.CW'   FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE bestand ( artikelnr, neu_datum, aender_datum, menge_ist ) AS
SELECT 220450002, DATE '2019-10-30', DATE '2019-11-01', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 220450002, DATE '2019-11-01', DATE '2019-11-05', 19 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 220502004, DATE '2019-11-05', DATE '2019-11-03',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 220800004, DATE '2019-11-01', DATE '2019-11-15', 35 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 221355002, DATE '2019-10-20', DATE '2019-11-05',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 221355002, DATE '2019-10-25', DATE '2019-11-10',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 221355002, DATE '2019-10-28', DATE '2019-11-13',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 221355002, DATE '2019-10-30', DATE '2019-11-15',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 221355002, DATE '2019-11-05', DATE '2019-11-20',  5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ARTIKELBEZEICHNUNG | ARTIKELNUMMER | MONTH               | MIN_TOTAL_MENGE_IST | MAX_TOTAL_MENGE_IST
> :----------------- | ------------: | :------------------ | ------------------: | ------------------:
> SC-4400.CW         |     220450002 | 2019-11-01 00:00:00 |                   0 |                  39
> S-320.FK120        |     220502004 | 2019-11-01 00:00:00 |                   0 |                   0
> AC-548.FK209       |     220948032 | 2019-11-01 00:00:00 |                   0 |                   0
> H-595.FK120        |     220800004 | 2019-11-01 00:00:00 |                   0 |                  35
> AS-6800.CW         |     221355002 | 2019-11-01 00:00:00 |                   0 |                  25
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=deb4dc31cc51b4745b0937fc0780ccf7)*

Comment: @MTO, wow great thanks, will now try and break it down to see how it works. I need to see if it is possible to modify this to deliver the same results but between 2 Dates. e.g. between 01.01.2020 and 31.12.2020.  List each month between the dates with Min and Max values.

Comment: @JRidge You want something like this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ee070a45919a207c6090c9eb6570cc0e) (it has some comments added and the code has been separated slightly more to make it easier to understand).

Comment: @MTO, great thank you very much, will start playing with it :)

Comment: @JRidge Should have been [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bc7311519a8432c4d82e0c7f76069cb9) with a few extra comments.